# Incremental string decoding in Java

Tags: java

Suppose I receive bytes in chunks and I want to efficiently decode them to a string (that is going to be Unicode obviously), also I want to know, as soon as I can, if that string begins with a certain sequence.

One way could be:

```
public boolean inputBytesMatch(InputStream inputStream, String match) throws IOException {
        byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        int len;
        while ((len = inputStream.read(buff)) > 0){
            byteArrayOutputStream.write(buff, 0, len);
            String decoded = new String(byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray(), Charset.defaultCharset());
            if (decoded.startsWith(match)){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

but this involves allocating a new array from the byteArrayOutputStream every time there is a new chunk and String will do another copy in the constructor. All this seems to me pretty inefficient. Also string will do a decode of the bytes in the constructor, every single time, doing it from the beginning once again.

How can I make this process faster?

Comment: What about to wrap `inputStream` for example to `BufferedReader` and read input with specific encoding? (e.g. `UTF-8`). Then, you would convert your `match` String to `byte[]` (with same encoding) and compare individual bytes of these two.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you don't need a `ByteArrayOutputStream` at all.

First turn your `String match` into a `byte[]`, using your desired encoding.
Then just compare each incoming chunk with the next part of that array:

```
public boolean inputBytesMatch(InputStream inputStream, String match) throws IOException {
    byte[] compare = match.getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset());
    int n = compare.length;

    int compareAt = 0;
    byte[] buff = new byte[n];

    int len;
    while (compareAt < n && (len = inputStream.read(buff, 0, n-compareAt)) > 0) {
        for (int i=0; i < len && compareAt < n; i++, compareAt++) {
            if (compare[compareAt] != buff[i]) {
                // found contradicting byte
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    // No byte was found which contradicts that the streamed data begins with compare.
    // Did we actually read enough bytes?
    return compareAt >= n;
}
```

You might find this version more readable:

```
public boolean inputBytesMatch(InputStream inputStream, String match) throws IOException {
    byte[] compare = match.getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset());
    int n = compare.length;

    int compareAt = 0;
    byte[] buff = new byte[n];

    int len;
    while (compareAt < n && (len = inputStream.read(buff, 0, n-compareAt)) > 0) {
        if (!isSubArray(compare, compareAt, buff, len)) {
            return false;
        }
        compareAt += len;
    }

    return compareAt >= n;
}

private boolean isSubArray(byte[] searchIn, int searchInOffset, byte[] searchFor, int searchForLength)
{
    if (searchInOffset + searchForLength >= searchIn.length) {
        // can not match
        return false;
    }

    for (int i=0; i < searchForLength; i++) {
        if (searchIn[searchInOffset+i] != searchFor[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: you can add some minor optimizations that you only read the required bytes max.  `inputStream.read(buff, 0, n-compareAt)`. You might include an extra read after you compared enough bytes `compareAt<n` should be first part of the condition.

Comment: Indeed, that was just a first quick try. I'll include your recommendations.

Comment: I knew someone would came up with this solution. That is perfectly valid don't get me wrong. But the string compare matching criteria was just an example use case, for a larger problem... suppose that the matching criteria is more complex, like a regular expression for example. How could that be done, without allocating a string every time a chunk is received?

Comment: If you want to avoid creating actual strings but have to work with string-like data look out for methods accepting CharSequence and use a StringBuilder as a dynamically growing buffer instead of Strings, which gets filled chunk by chunk. To actually get character chunks wrap your InputStream into a Reader. Your example of pattern matching supports this through Pattern#match(CharSequence).